# How do I copy files from the current directory, but not sub-directories using a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a school assignment and I am stuck on this one question. I have no idea where else to turn.

So this question follows on from the previous question which is to make a script to copy "myfile.txt" to my environment variable %BackUpPath% (which is set to C:\backup). My script is as follows:

- **copy /y myfile.txt %backuppath%**

The question I'm stuck on asks me to make a script using an IF EXIST statement in conjunction with a FOR loop to copy all the files in the current directory, but not any sub-directories to %backuppath%.

How should I write this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the question, but it's academic rather than a real life code.

It uses the recursive switch of `for-in-do` and checks if the `filename.ext` that is generated by the for-in-do actually exists in the current directory - and then copies those files.

```
@echo off
set "backuppath=c:\folder"
for /r %%a in (*) do (
    if exist "%cd%\%%~nxa" (
       echo copying "%%a"
       copy "%%a" "%backuppath%" >nul
    )
)
```

Comment: A better method that occurs to me now is to check that the drive:\path of the file is equal to the current directory.  The code above can copy files twice or more if the same filename exists in the current directory as well as somewhere else in the directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

try these commands in what ever order

`@echo off
tree "C:\backup" 
find /c "*.TXT" C:\Backup
if exists "file path\name"
move /y "files within the folder to other folder"
del /f /s "main file-path"
for each %.txt IN C:\Backup goto a
<replace move with copy if needed>
;;this is a rough idea of what you might need.`

Comment: I wish I could just do that. I have to create a batch script for my class that does exactly what the question says :-(

Comment: you should be able to but you have to include a path also look at Computer hope.com for more commands and a better explanation of them